# chrome devtools: shortcut to elements panel subpanel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a Dev tools extension to add a subpanel to Elements panel. 
Extension is called 'Redder' ( see the image)

[image]

Is there a way to reach this extension with keyboard.

Right now chrome has a short cut keys to launch Dev tools and switch between main panels but not the sub panels (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts?hl=en#accessing-devtools)

Also, is there a way to assign shortcut key to go to my extension panel directly after launching Devtools?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but I don't think it's possible.

Even if you made a shortcut listener, there is no API to programmatically switch to your panel.